# get email or other contact information from craigslist using python request

Tags: python, email, web-scraping, python-requests, craigslist

I am trying to figure out a way I can get email or tel from **craigslists** using **python**.

I have used python-craigslist to get the post but there is nothing I am able to find regarding emails or other contact info

I tried this:

```
import requests

url = "https://chandigarh.craigslist.org/reply/ixc/hum/7220389776/mailto"

head = {
"Accept": "*/*",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Content-Length": "344",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"DNT": "1",
"Host": "chandigarh.craigslist.org",
"Origin": "https://chandigarh.craigslist.org",
"Referer": "https://chandigarh.craigslist.org/hum/d/hr-outsourcing-company-in-mohali/7220389776.html",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
post_data = {"n": "U2FsdGVkX184MDg3MTgwOF5nEvY336v771unnxU7b9fc52-DzxhmmxcCYwQ6uylAsvUK2atZ1Ot3zWsSF4ukqvM9BMFMnNA_L00i0jQ5DhiZkfobQq1avkovyPJ3IcQbWM4327VdEQUipMzU6XfOXn5xsLqQ9Tt-L1qJdM55e2Ac11nzeaFCRV7HgpYmmIdrjpESKZpp0dhTh2p5d826f9CSBa4ldNRg0pLswm5P3JXaYGTe4Z7Fe5NB1Jfs3-CBWFdy2ZzqIA345q_YfXUatIMoq1TwN3lc_ee8rKnLKJmQwPHPpLoQHRP9aioeMOBv17okylBLm8uhduZ6HawCRg"}

resp = requests.post(url, headers=head,data= post_data)

print(resp.text)
```

**but no response**

Answer (score 1):

Following is my code I got the email successfully.

1. getting the email ifram to get this link
   [image]
2. solving the captcha using 2captch
3. sending the solved captcha response to get the next token
4. than sending post request to with that token to mailto to get the email.
5. Also it uses different headers for each request so I hardcoded different headers for each request.

   ```
   resp = r.post(url, headers=head, data=post_data, allow_redirects=True)
   asd = resp.json()
   capin = str(asd["nonce"])
   print("Capcha In Request Successfull...")

   solver = TwoCaptcha("API_KEY")

   try:
       print("Solving Captcha Using 2Captcha")
       result = solver.hcaptcha(
           sitekey='0c3a1de8-e8df-4e01-91b6-6995c4ade451',
           url=ifram_url
       )

   except Exception as e:
       print(e)

   else:
       captcha = result["code"]
       print("Captcha Solved Successfully")

   post_data1 = {"h-captcha-response": str(captcha),
                 "n": capin
                 }
   url1 = capt_link
   c_len = len(captcha)+len(capin)+22
   head1 = {
       "Accept": "*/*",
       "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
       "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
       "Connection": "keep-alive",
       "Content-Length": str(c_len),
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
       "Cookie": cookie,
       "DNT": "1",
       "Host": host,
       "Origin": origin,
       "Referer": main_url,
       "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
       "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
       "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36",
       "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
   }

   resp = r.post(url1, headers=head1, data=post_data1, allow_redirects=True)
   bsd = resp.json()
   capout = str(bsd["nonce"])
   print("Captcha Out Request Successfull...")

   c_len1 = len(capout)+2

   post_data2 = {"n": capout}
   url2 = milto_link
   head2 = {
       "Accept": "*/*",
       "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
       "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
       "Connection": "keep-alive",
       "Content-Length": str(c_len1),
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
       "Cookie": cookie,
       "DNT": "1",
       "Host": host,
       "Origin": origin,
       "Referer": main_url,
       "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
       "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
       "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36",
       "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
   }

   resp = r.post(url2, headers=head2, data=post_data2, allow_redirects=True)

   defg = resp.json()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(defg["email"], "html.parser")
   email = soup.find("input").get("value")
   print(email)
   Final_Email.append(email)
   ```

Comment: hey Muhammad can you send me the full script?

Comment: You can view my GitHub and take the code from there thanks! https://github.com/rajasaad7/CraigsList-Scrapper

Comment: hey Muhammad I'm sorry for annoying you but I changed a little your code and it doesn't print in the terminal the email, it prints "nonce". I'm just using the email_grabber.py by running it directly in the terminal. here's the code: https://zerobin.net/?10fb10c008c50927#s3lCDMUWDW4SUpxzPOMlyTTTgN7lao1MJNrcYLGFNWk=

Answer (score 0):

For scraping Craigslist, use the pyquery Python package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery

For a regex for email addresses / phone numbers, see the examples on this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

For storing the email addresses you can just output to csv. You can read on how to do it there: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

If you wouldd like to use this emails and send messages to them you might want to check this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mail-merge/

Also I advise you to stay on the bright side and read more there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morality

Comment: how are these regex working and how will I get an email address?